# How is float range that large with 4 bytes (±3.40282347E+38)

Tags: java, floating-point, int

Both `int` and `float` types are of **4 bytes** in java.

Then how can `int` represent a range of just `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647` where `float` has approximately `±3.40282347E+38F` while both have the same limited amount of bytes?

According to my understanding both should have the same range as they have the same amount of bytes. Can some one explain me how `float` can represent a range that large?

Comment: Learn about [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Floating-point_numbers). Basically, it doesn't represent _every_ real number from -3*10^38 to 3*10^38

Comment: [*Single-precision floating-point format*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) in Wikipedia.

Comment: There's an infinite number of real numbers between -3*10^38 and 3*10^38, so naturally, the float type can represent only a tiny fraction of them, regardless of how many bytes you use. Since it has a larger range than the `int` type, this means that the float type cannot even represent all the integer numbers in that range.

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094022/why-does-floating-point-numbers-have-uneven-spacing-on-the-number-line) might also be helpful.

Comment: Scaling.  Basically a binary floating point number represents mantissa x 2^scale.  Where the mantissa and the scale are packed into the 32 bit floating point representation.  That means that there are approximately 2^32 different values, that are spread *unevenly* over the range.

Comment: It is interesting people ask this about floating-point numbers without realizing there is a similar problem in “How do we represent integers from −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 with just 32 bits?” Binary is so ingrained or intuitive people do not think the bits are a **code** for a number: The first bit means 1, the next 2, then 4, 8, 16, and so on. There is no actual number in them, not even a direct proportion from voltage or charge to magnitude. It is a code. For floating-point, we use a different code. Some bits mean 1, 2, 4, 8, and so on, and some bits mean “multiply by a power of two”.

Comment: @Eran "represent only a tiny fraction of" "infinite number",  Hmmm 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Floating" point means that the number of digits for the fractional part of your number can change to represent your number "as best as possible" given the constraints dictated by its size.

Let's forget for the time being of the 4 bytes of the *float* datatype and assume that you your "floating point" type can store up to 10 digits plus the negative symbol.
This means you can accurately represent numbers from :`-9 999 999 999` to `+9 999 999 999`.
However, if you want one decimal, you can accurately represent numbers from `-999 999 999.9` to `+999 999 999.9`. As you can see, the range has effectively changed.

Now, let's formalize a bit the explanation by talking about *significand* and *exponent*:

- the *significand* contains your significant digits
- the *exponent* represents the exponent of the 10 multiplier or, if it's easier, by how many positions you have to move the decimal point (with 0 being just before the first significant digit).

Let's say that your "floating point" data type can have up to 4 digits in its *significand* and up to 1 digit in its *exponent* as well, plus the minus symbol in both *significand* and *exponent*.
You will be able to represent numbers from `-0.9 999 * 10^9 = -999900000` to `+0.999 9 * 10^9 = +999900000`. As you can see while the numbers are pretty large you can't accurately represent most large numbers as you only have 4 digits you can use for your representation. This loss in precision is compensated by the ability to represent very small numbers so for example you can represent `0.999 9 * 10^-9 = 0.000 000 000 999 9`.

This explains why the range is so large despite the size being only 4 bytes, as stated in your question.

---

To complete your knowledge on the matter, bring the above concepts to binary (your typical `float` uses 4 bits for the *exponent*, 23 for the *significand* and 1 bit for the sign of the significand).

Wikipedia is a good starting point. The major takeaway from programming purposes, usually, is to understand how many decimal digits you can store given your datatype (your "precision") as that will determine what specific decimal format fits your purposes best.

See the following link for more information:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers

Please note that understanding the concept of *floating point* number on a binary system is extremely important in information technology as even the most simple computations are heavily affected by it.

Floating points as represented on a computer (binary) are for example the reason why writing things like:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      double x=0.1f;
      double y=0.2f;
      double z=0.3f;

      if(x+y == z) {
          System.out.println("something");
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("something else");
      }
    }
}
```

will counter-intuitively output `something else` but if you start playing with the numbers or change the type to *float* it will produce the correct output.

So be aware: you will need to understand the concept fully.

Comment: Note that your code example is javascript, the question is tagged with java though.

Comment: Damn my laziness... :)

Comment: The preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point number is “significand.” “Mantissa” is an old term for the fractional portion of a logarithm. Mantissas are logarithmic (adding to a mantissa will multiply the represented value) while significands are linear (adding to a significand will add something to the represented value, according to the exponent scale).

Comment: Yep. Will modify the answer.